# Is it possible to change the endpoint at which Kamon Prometheus reporter exposes the metrics?

Tags: prometheus, kamon, akka-monitoring

By default kamon-prometheus exposes the metrics at http://localhost:9095. Is it possible to change it ,eg : http://localhost:9095/metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved .Without any additional configuration ,it gave the metrics at the desired endpoint.Whatever is given after http://localhost:9095 it scrapes and returns the metrics.